# Why can't we devise a sufficiently simple mathematical system such that it is provably consistent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms, decidability

I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I'm under the impression that we cannot devise a set of axioms that results in a provably consistent mathematical system. Why is that?

If my impression is wrong, what exactly about ZFC causes it to have unprovable consistency?

Edit: I'd like to ask an additional question. If we started with the "simplest" axiom from ZFC, and started adding more and more axioms from ZFC, at what point would the consistency become unprovable?

Comment: Different things are provable in different mathematical systems, so whether a given mathematical system is *provably* consistent depends on which mathematical system you are attempting to prove its consistency in.

Comment: Saying more in the same vein as @spaceisdarkgreen, we _can_ prove the consistency of certain mathematical systems. For instance, from inside of ZFC we can prove the consistency of [Peano Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) -- after all, $\mathbb{N}$ is a model. Similarly, in ZFC+"there exists an [inaccessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal)" we can prove that ZFC is consistent (in fact, we can get by with slightly less). However, what we _can't_ do is use ZFC (or PA, or whatever) to prove its own consistency. This is a theorem of Goedel.

Comment: The empty set of axioms is consistent: No sentences at all are provable, so no false sentences are provable. This proof it's consistent requires only a very simple logic theory, but again this logic theory is obviously not the set of axioms we're examining.

Comment: _"Why can't we devise a sufficiently simple mathematical system such that it is provably consistent?"_ We have. An example is [Tarski's formulation of Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms), and it can be [proven to be consistent in a relatively weak metatheory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261416).

Answer (score 2):

Whether we can prove the consistency of some given system $X$ or not depends on what mathematical system we are working in (often referred to as "the metatheory"). If we use a strong metatheory we can prove more things than a weaker one, including proving that more systems are consistent, which is nice. On the other hand, if we use *too* strong of a metatheory, then we can prove wrong things, or even prove everything, and that's no good.

Strong systems can often prove the consistency of weaker ones. For instance, MK proves the consistency of ZFC, which proves the consistency of Z, which proves the consistency PA, which proves the consistency of PRA. But Gödel's theorem says roughly that no system (worth a hill of beans) can prove its own consistency, so a weaker system can prove a stronger system consistent.

So if we take our metatheory to be ZFC, then there you go... Gödel tells us that the consistency of ZFC is unprovable there. But the consistency of lots of weaker systems, e.g. Z, PA, PRA is provable.

To your last question, if again we're taking ZFC as our metatheory, it happens to be the case that ZFC proves the consistency of any finite subtheory of ZFC, so you can keep adding axioms forever in that sense. If you're wondering how many we can delete before it becomes provably consistent, the answer is 1 (if you choose the right one)... e.g. ZFC-P (where P is the power set axiom) is provably consistent in ZFC.

Comment: On "worth a hill of beans" - I might be confusing popular summaries of Gödel's Incompleteness theorem with the actual statement, but I think the idea is that the theorem applies if the system is "useful enough" to be able to build and manipulate descriptions of its own formulas and axioms and proofs (e.g. using Gödel numbers)?

Comment: @aschepler The first incompleteness theorem applies to any consistent, recursively axiomatizable, extension of Robinson arithmetic. The (usual statement of) the second theorem requires a bit more: that the provability predicate you can construct on the basis of the aformentioned conditions satisfies the [derivability conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Bernays_provability_conditions).

Comment: So I guess, to answer my question completely, you're stating that no metatheory can prove its own consistency, unless the number of axioms is trivial (equal to one, if you choose a right one)?

Comment: @BastionBanner No, it can’t prove its own consistency ever, even if it only has one axiom (and note having finitely many axioms is effectively the same thing as having one since we can consider a single sentence that is the conjunction of all the axioms.) The thing with ZFC is that it has infinitely many axioms, and the fact that it can prove any finite number consistent just means that ZFC isn’t equivalent to any finite subset of its axioms and moreover isn’t finitely axiomatizable.